# git ignore_global set but not being used by git

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I've read solutions from other questions git ignore files, but I still can't get it to work.

So here's what I've done:

1. created `.gitignore_global` file.
2. added `.mp3 .mp4 .oog .wmv .wma` then saved.
3. executed this command :

`git config --global core.excludesfile .gitignore_global`

but when i commit it still adds my mp3 files. I even tried `git rm -r --cached .` then `git add .` to clear the cache, but even after that it still adds it back. what I'm I missing here?

Comment: Where did you create `.gitignore_global`? Does it work if you set `core.excludesfile` to include the full path to the file, instead of just the file name? Also you probably want to use `*.mp3` instead of `.mp3` (which will probably never match an existing file...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try adding to `.gitignore_global` the following line :

```
# Audio files #
###############

*.mp3 
*.mp4 
*.oog 
*.wmv 
*.wma
```

See documentation [Ignoring-files](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files).

Comment: yeah I used the `*` symbol earlier, but I removed it after clearing the cache. my bad.